# Correct usage of both Navigation Drawer and Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I'm struggling to understand how Google wants an app to behave when both a navigation drawer and tabs are needed.

Since fragments cannot/shouldn't be nested, wouldn't it make sense that the navigation drawer cycled through Activities and not Fragments? Thus, in their turn, each activity could be a tabbed view, etc.

My issue in code is that the Navigation Drawer (as per demo/examples) start with a Main Activity for the parent and provide Fragments of different views.

A `ViewPager` with swipe tabs has a `FragmentActivity` as its parent and `Fragment`s as the child.

Bad enough that most examples are mixed between the `android.support.v4` libiraries and the native ones, I might be missing something else?

I am assuming that for my purposes, I should be using a Navigation Drawer to cycle Activities and then continue from there. Is that a 'correct' design or should I be doing something different?

TIA

*edit*

I'll be more specific:
Under the support library, how can I implement the below:

```
Parent: MainActivity (has navdrawer)
Child of Main: SwipeActivity1 (has swipe tabs)
Child of Swipe: ContentPage1 (has content)
```

**Should that be, FragmentActivity -> FragmentActivity -> Fragment ?**

When not using the support library, how is this done? (and non-nested fragments)

**Should it be, Activity -> Fragment -> Fragment ?**

Comment: Fragments can be nested

Comment: @gunar, indeed, just read it now for Android 4.2 API, but lets assume this is for 4.0.3+ (API 15+)

Comment: Viewpager is in the compatibility package so why don't base your activities with `FragmentActivity`? It will work on all platforms

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're facing?

Comment: @gunar, so you're saying have the MainActivity use a NavDrawer that cycles through FragmentActivities which in turn provide Fragments, all in support.v4 library?

Comment: What do you mean by `cycle through FragmentActivities` ? And yes, all my Activities are extending from `FragmentActivity/ActionBarActivity` since the minSDK needs to be 9. The only exceptions are for Preferences since there Google didn't provide compatibility support

Comment: I want to know the correct approach in design. Is it Activity -> FragmentActivity -> Fragment ? Also, can I do it in the v13/native libraries? (they don't have FragmentActivity), ty.

Comment: You can use any `Fragment <-> FragmentActivity` redirections since `FragmentActivity is-an Activity`. v13 support library includes v4 if you take a look inside

Comment: So I should have my main activity as a FragmentActivity and thus have FragmentActivity -> FragmentActivity -> Fragment ?

Comment: I would say yes, but what is your use-case? We're talking about a too general topic.

Comment: see edit then you can post answer and ty

Comment: Answer as what? I get the feeling you have the answer, but reading the question all over again, I still don't understand what you're really asking in there ... Makes sense? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are many ways to accomplish this, and thanks to gunar for his help.

I managed to accomplish the below (for the support libraries android.support.v4):

```
Parent: MainActivity (has navdrawer)
Child of Main: SwipeActivity1 (has swipe tabs)
Child of Swipe: ContentPage1 (has content)
```

They are: FragmentActivity -> Fragment -> Fragment.

The first had to have some form of Activity, so I could launch it, and then all sub screens worked fine as activities.

I am still not 100% certain this is the 'optimal' approach, but seems to be working fine.

I am still unaware of how this would be done with the native/v13 libraries.